# Secondary Join Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, join

I have your typical M:M relationship - think of the `User`/`Role` example:

#### USER, ROLE, USER_ROLE

I need a second USER_ROLE table to audit actions the User performs and which Role they were at the time the action was performed. I am looking for a way to accomplish this with JPA AND without changing up the `User` and `Role` Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it could be something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE")
public class UserRole {
    ... // id, additional columns go here

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") 
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") 
    private Role role;
    ...
```